# What is mappedList and x from the list l?

Tags: functional-programming, f#

What is mappedList and x if you have the list l as input?

```
let mapFold (f: 'a -> 'b) (l : List<'a>) : List<'b> =
    l |> List.fold (fun mappedList x -> f x :: mappedList) [] |> List.rev
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda expression (indicated by the `fun` keyword) defines the folder function, which has the type `'State -> 'T -> 'State` where State is also sometimes referred to as the accumulator, abbreviated as `acc`. And `'T` is the type of an element of the list `l`.

A simple example: `(0, [1..10]) ||> List.fold (fun acc x -> acc + x)`
in which 0 is the initial value of the state (or acc), and `x` is an element of the list `[1..10]`.

So to answer your question, `mappedList` is the state or accumulator, which has the initial value `[]` or `List.empty`, and `x` is an element of the list `l`. The fold function will apply the folder function to each element 'x' of the list in sequence from beginning to end, updating and returning the value of the state with each call, and finally returning the final value of the state.